# Project and triangulate a vector. From 3D to 2D and viceversa

Tags: algorithms, 3d, projection, triangulation

I'm having some issues when projecting a 3D vector in an image with known pose, and triangulating two 2D lines in two images with known poses.

---

**Project 3D vector**

Let's suppose we have a vector `v_world = (x_v, y_v, z_v)` in world coordinates. I want to project it in an image taken from a camera with known intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. The pose of this camera is an homogeneous matrix 4x4 `Tcw`. For a vector projection, I only need the rotation 3x3 submatrix `Rcw`. Let's get the vector `v` in camera coordinates.

```
v_camera = Rcw * v_world
```

This would be the same as.

```
(v_camera, 0) = Tcw * (v_world, 0)
```

To get now the vector in 2D, I just have to ignore the depth dimension and realize this operation.

```
v_camera_2D = atan2(v_camera[1], v_camera[0])
```

---

**Triangulate two 2D lines**

[image: Triangulation]

Let's suppose I want to triangulate two lines. The first one pass through the pixel `(x_1, y_1)` in the first image with known optical center `(cx_1, cy_2)`, focal length `(fx_1, fy_1)` and pose `Tcw_1`. Second line pass through the pixel `(x_2, y_2)` in the second image with known optical center `(cx_2, cy_2)`, focal length `(fx_2, fy_2)` and pose `Tcw_2`. Both lines' orientation are also known, `v_1` and `v_2`, in given images.

I want to triangulate these lines to get the world orientation of the 3D line.

My first step is to construct the plane that contains the 2D line and the optical center of the camera. The 3D line will be the the intersection of the two constructed planes in both images. This is, the cross products of the planes' normal vector.

I just need then the normal vector of the desired planes. For this, I calculate the vector from the optical center to the line point.

```
v_plane1 = ( (x_1 - cx_1) / fx_1, (y_1 - cy_1) / fy_1, 1)
```

And convert it to world coordinates.

```
v_plane1_world = (Rcw)^T * v_plane
```

I convert too the 2D line orientation to 3D world coordinates.

```
v_line1 = ( cos(v_1), sin(v_1), 0 )
v_line1_world = (Rcw)^T * v_line1
```

The normal vector of the desired plane is the cross product of its two containing vectors.

```
v_normal_plane1_world = v_plane1_world x v_line1_world
```

And the orientation of the 3D line will be.

```
v_world = v_normal_plane1_world x v_normal_plane2_world
```

---

I have implemented it and doesn't work. I create an initial 3D line. I project it in two images, and triangulate both projections again. The triangulation and the initial 3D line should be the same (with a float precision threshold). Both lines are the same when I create a basic 3D line (an horizontal line, for example) and project it in two basic images (with any rotation). But the lines don't match when doing the same with rotated and translated images.

Is there any step I am wrongly doing? I don't pay attention to the vectors' magnitude, because I only want the orientation. I can upload my code to a repository if it's needed.

Comment: Can you label the diagram? I am having trouble understanding what is what exactly.

Comment: I don't see any inverse correction for perspective in your calculations, something that would convert the actual clipped conical-like view from the camera to the parallelepipeds of your model.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy You mean in the projection? I'm just interested in projecting the orientation of the line (the projection of a line's point is working fine for me, and I care about the inverse correction that I guess you mean). I think that in the orientation projection, I don't have to care about it.

Comment: No. I mean the perspective. That is a different projection, taking into account the focal depth of the cameras.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Yes, I take into account the focal depth in the perspective projection of a point `x_2D = f * (x_3D / z_3D)`. But I don't see why I should care about it in the projection of a vector. To get the 2D orientation, I realize the atan operation, and `atan2(y_3D, x_3D) = atan2(f*(y_3D / z_3D), f*(x_3D / z_3D)) = atan2(y_2D, x_2D)`